Exclude specific phrase from existing regular expression
This regular expression detects any UK post codes:
([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})

I would like to blacklist/exclude a certain post codes for example 'GU14 6XM'
Flavor: PCRE (PHP <7.3)
Regex flags: global, multi line, insensitive & single line
I have tried to combine the following into the existing Regex but I cannot get it to work, they work individually but not together.
^(?!.GU14 6XM).$
Also tried using
(?=) - positive lookahead
(?!) - negative lookahead
(?<=) - positive lookbehind
(?<!) - negative lookbehind

([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9][A-Za-z]?))))\s?[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})(?<!GU14 6XM).*

I would like the post code GU14 6XM to be ignored but should GU14 6XP or any other combination of UK post code appear I need that to trigger.

Do  you mean like this? ^(?!.*GU14 6XM) or ^(?!GU14 6XM)([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2}).....

Where are these post codes? Inside some text or you match from start to end? If they are in text, how are they separated from the text, by whitespace? Why use i flag but list upper and lower a-z? For what all these groups? Try something like \b(?i)(?:gir 0aa|(?!gu14 ?6xm)(?:[a-z](?:\d(?:[a-z]|\d?)|[a-hj-y]\d[\da-z]?)) ?\d[a-z]{2})\b using word boundaries \b for separation. Most likely made some mistake by resolving the parentheses-convolution but an idea!

A version without all that is useless: https://regex101.com/r/j7EPcR/1

@bobblebubble The post codes are in the UK, usually they are separated with a space for example 'GU14 6XM' but could be 'GU146XM' I want to use this to scan email content. Thank you so much this works perfectly! Can I exclude more than one post code?

@HopefulRiver If they occur in text using word boundaries \b should be fine. Yes you can exclude more post codes using alternation: (?!gu14 ?6xm|...|...) or whatever pattern you put inside the negative lookahead.
